# I want a note template having two column format

Tags: notes

I am making a conclusion of many articles and classifying. I hope the template could include title, chapter, section, and the main text can be two columns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{foo}
\begin{document}
\maketitle \chapter{foo} \section{foo} \lipsum
\end{document}`

Comment: @Fran Great! I like this template !